# Using regex to validate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate image files before they are uploaded using javascript/jquery.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$('#cropimages').click(function(){
    i = 1 ;
    var valid = new RegExp('/^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/') ;
    $('input').each(function(){

        if($(this).attr('name') == 'file'+i)
        {
            val = $(this).val() ;

            r = valid.exec(val) ;
            alert(r) ;
            i++ ;
        }
    })
    //$('#topperform').submit()
})
```

But it keeps coming back `null` no matter what kind of file I choose.

What do I need to do to my `RegExp` to make this work?

Comment: By the way, I would make your regular expression case insensitive `var valid = /^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i;` just in case your file contains extensions in uppercase like `.JPG`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regular expression literal:

```
var valid = /^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/;
```

If you *really* want to use the RegExp consturctor then omit the delimiters.

```
var valid = new RegExp('^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$');
```

**Related**

- [Regular Expressions - Javascript (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: One tiny thing; you don't need the `new` keyword when instantiating a RegExp :)